# How can I access global javascript variables in the browser console?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

This is kind of annoying when developing javascript inside Visualforce: I can not find my global variables !

---

Build a Visualforce page with showHeader="false"

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
```

Create a javascript global variable inside the page:

```
<script> var myVar = 'Hello'; </script>
```

Save your test page and open it via its URL.

```
http//[instance].salesforce.com/apex/[pagename]
```

Now in the browser console (F12 sometimes), type

```
window.myVar
```

and return gives you

```
'Hello'
```

---

**Now** insert this visualforce page as a section in a standard page layout.

Load the standard page and type in the console:

```
window.myVar
```

Which returns

```
undefined
```

*What ?*

Where art thou ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the standard page layout, visualforce pages are embedded in `<iframe/>` and the browser console show variable in scope of main page not their iframe (child frame). You can change the scope by selecting the frame.

As shown in image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The VF page is loaded inside a frameset and so will not be where you are expecting. Perhaps something like window.frames[x].myVar will give you what you need?